# Too many queries in production environment

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

In dev environment there are 16 database queries (using doctrine 2.6 & only dql queries in my repositories). Somehow in production the exact same page shows 101 queries - because all the relations are queried, even most of them are not used. I have tried different fetch modes like EAGER but it didn't change anything.

Here is a sample annotation which gets queried but is never used on the page:

```
/**
 * @var Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @Assert\Valid(traverse=true)
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Translation", mappedBy="origin", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true, fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"locale"="ASC"})
 */
private $translations;
```

Could it be some kind of configuration error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it – the root cause was apcu. When I switched from:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver: apcu
        query_cache_driver: apcu
        result_cache_driver: apcu
```

to

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver: apc
        query_cache_driver: apc
        result_cache_driver: apc
```

I got down to 9 requests instead of 16 (dev) and 101 (prod via apcu). Maybe it was some server side issue with the module.